# SPARQL/DBPedia: Fetch entity via properties without knowing entity page URI

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to return a property from an entity describing a company/stock on DBPedia given a unique combination of other properties that that entity belongs to.

For example, given the strings `NASDAQ` and `AAPL`, I want to be able to find the http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc. page without explicitly knowing the URI.

I know that this page contains properties

- `dbp:symbol`: `AAPL`
- `dbp:tradedAs`: `dbr:NASDAQ-100`

How would I use SPARQL to search `dbp:symbol` for `AAPL` directly and search `dbp:tradedAs` for a partial match on `NASDAQ`, to return the most likely result, if one exists.

I also must add that the property I want to return from this page, if there's a match, is `dbo:abstract` which corresponds to a large textual description of the company/stock which I'd like to use for parsing.

**EDIT:** I've managed to execute the following:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?s1 dbpedia2:symbol ?o1 .
   ?s1 dbpedia2:tradedAs ?o2 .
   ?o1 bif:contains  '"AAPL"'  .
}
```

which returns entries

```
s1  o1  o2
:Apple_Inc. [http]  "AAPL"^^rdf:langString  :S&P_500 
:Apple_Inc.    [http]   "AAPL"^^rdf:langString  :Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average    
:Apple_Inc. [http]  "AAPL"^^rdf:langString  :NASDAQ-100
```

I tried to add `?o2 bif:contains  'NASDAQ'` but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: do you understand why `?o2 bif:contains  'NASDAQ'`? `bif:contains` is a fulltext index only on literals, but the values for `dbp:tradedAs` are URIs in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it:

```
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?s1 dbpedia2:symbol ?symbol .
   ?s1 dbpedia2:tradedAs ?exchange .
   ?s1 dbo:abstract ?abstract .
   ?symbol bif:contains  '"AAPL"'  .
   FILTER(lang(?abstract) = "en").
   FILTER(regex(str(?exchange), "NASDAQ" ) )
}
```

which returns

```
s1  symbol  exchange    abstract
:Apple_Inc. "AAPL"^^rdf:langString  :NASDAQ-100 "Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Cupertino, California...
```

Just to note, specifically for this entry, `rdfs:comment` is more useful for a quick summary of the company.

Comment: `rdfs:comment` is always the same as or a shorter part of `dbo:abstract`. An alternative of your `regex` scan over the URIs would be to use the `bif:contains` filter on the English  label of the `?exchange` node. I.e. `?exchange rdfs:label  ?exchangeLabel .
   ?exchangeLabel bif:contains  '"NASDAQ"'  
   FILTER(lang(?abstract) = "en" && lang(?exchangeLabel) = "en").`

Comment: @AKSW Perfect, thanks very much. Out of curiosity, I'm finding it easier to find items by stock/exchange via Wikidata. Is there a way to bridge the gap and find the item via Wikidata and then get its `rdfs:comment` from DBPedia? I'm aware this may be too big an ask for comments, may make into own question.

Comment: From Wikidata or from DBpedia as starting point? If you're able to identify the entity in Wikidata, you can use a federated SPARQL query like this: `SELECT ?entity ?comment WHERE {
 
  BIND(<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q312> as ?entity)
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    ?s owl:sameAs ?entity .
    ?s rdfs:comment ?comment   
       filter(langmatches(lang(?comment),"en"))
  }
}` and make use of the `owl:sameAs` links in DBpedia. Note, here I just "hard-coded" the part in Wikidata where you have to identify the entity via the exchange properties in Wikidata

Comment: @AKSW I did want to ask, is there a more efficient way of returning `owl:sameAs` entities, say if I had a list of wikidata links and wanted the DBPedia comment equivalent; something like fetching them row by row?

Comment: what do you mean by "more efficient"? I also don't know what you mean by "list". In SPARQL you can use `VALUES` to provide inline data similar: `VALUES ?p {:e1 :e2 :e3 ... :en}` - is that what you want?